# ERROR: The DSP mongodb.dsp does not exist

Tags: mongodb, pecl

I am trying to install the MongoDB driver on windows with pecl like so :

```
pecl install mongodb-beta
```

and receive this error :

```
ERROR: The DSP mongodb.dsp does not exist.
```

From a web search it seems this is because it is not thread safe but I can't seem to find a thread safe package.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to download the library manually if you are on a windows box:

https://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb

Comment: And put it where?

Comment: Put the dll from the package into php/ext/ dir (assuming php binary is in the php/ dir).